# Combine Q object and prefetch_related in Django?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I'm trying to implement a keyword search like so:

```
keyword = request.GET['keyword']

books = Book.objects.all()
books = books.filter(
    Q(title__contains=keyword) |
    Q(summary__contains=keyword) |
    Q(author__name__contains=keyword) |
    Q(author__biography__contains=keyword) |
)
```

With the following models:

```
class Book(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    title = models.CharField()
    summary = models.CharField()
    author = models.ManyToManyField('Author', through='BookToAuthor')

class BookToAuthor(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    book_id = models.ForeignKey('Book')
    author_id = models.ForeignKey('Author')

class Author(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    name = models.CharField()
    biography = models.CharField()
```

Everything works as expected, but the query execution alone is taking a significant amount of time (10-15 seconds). Through trial and error, I've been able to determine that this is caused by the ManyToMany Q() fields. I know I can use prefetch_related in order to cache/join the relational fields in Python and improve performance. But I'm having trouble getting this to work in combination with the (Q() | Q() ...) filtering.

Any suggestions on how to incorporate prefetch_related? Or an alternative method that would improve performance?

Comment: Have you tried this, `Book.objects.prefetch_related('author__name', 'author__biography').filter(
    Q(title__contains=keyword) | Q(summary__contains=keyword) | Q(author__name__contains=keyword) | Q(author__biography__contains=keyword))` ?

Comment: Yes, I get an error `'author__name' does not resolve to an item that supports prefetching - this is an invalid parameter to prefetch_related().`